# If $X $ is a random variable and $aX \sim bX $ then $ a = b $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$X $ is a random variable for which $\ P(X \not = 0 ) > 0 $ , and I have some $\ a, b \in [0, \infty) $ such that $\ F_{aX} = F_{bX} $ does it mean that $\ a = b $ ?

My understanding is that since $\ F_{aX}(t) = F_{bX}(t) $ for every $\ t \in \mathbb R $

then $$\mathbb P[(\omega \mid aX(\omega) \in (-\infty, t])]  = \mathbb P [(\omega \mid bX(\omega) \in (-\infty,t])] $$

then $$\ aX(\omega) = bX(\omega) \rightarrow \frac{a}{b} = 1 $$

Comment: Take $X\sim N(0, 1).$ Then $X\sim -X.$

Comment: OP has a, b nonnegative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is invalid. Just because two random variables have the same distribution you cannot say that the random variables are themselves equal. Here are some steps you can verify to answer this question:

Step I:  Suppose $a >b$. If $aX$ and $bX$ have the same distribution then $X$ has the same as distribution as $\frac b a X$.

Step II. We can iterate the result of Step I to see that $X$ has the same as distribution as $(\frac b a)^{n} X$ for each $n$.

Step III.  Since $(\frac b a)^{n} \to 0$ we can conclude that $X$ has the same distribution as $0$.  But this contradicts the hypothesis.

Finally we have proved that $a \leq b$ and a similar argument gives $b \leq a$ so $a=b$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Not sure on step I why does $\ X $ has the same as distribution as $\ \frac{b}{a}X $ ?

Comment: $P(\frac  b a X \leq x)=P(bX \leq ax)=P(aX \leq  aX) =P(X \leq x)$ where the second equality follows by hypothesis. @bm1125